# Why won't my 'position: fixed' nav bar remain at the centre of my document?

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a project on freeCodeCamp regarding a product placement page. The page is now asking me to fix my `#navbar` at the top of the viewport. Although this works with `position: fixed`, after I add the fixed position in CSS, the navbar no longer remains in the centre and moves to the left. If you remove `position: fixed;`, you'll see what I mean. Why is this happening?

Before adding the fixed position, the navbar was centred (UK spelling ;-}) via `margin-left: center;`, `margin-right: center;`. I also have my viewport as 800px wide with auto height (I.e. BBC style).

Important note: There was a logo I created of which I subsequently added to the document, but this does not seem to display (it's hosted by tinypic). If you can't see this logo, it's positioned between the title and the video.

Additional Info:
My video was centred before I made a change. If you could also help me with that, I'd appreciate it. But that's not the main point of this question.

```css
#mainbody {
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: garamond, serif;
}

#h1title {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 16px 8px 16px;
  font-size: 38px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#header-img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

  #nav-bar {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: black;
}

.nav-button {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.30;
}

#video {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#form {
  
}

legend {
  font-weight: 700;
}

#submit {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Quality Prints</title>
  </head>
  <body id="mainbody">
    <a name="home-link"></a>
    <header id="header">
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <button class="nav-button"><a class="nav-link" href="#home-link">Home</a></button>
        <button class="nav-button"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a></button>
        <button class="nav-button"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact-link">Contact</a></button>
      </nav>
      <h1 id="h1title">Quality Prints ™</h1><hr />
      <img id="header-img" src="http://i66.tinypic.com/157ltle.jpg">
      
    </header>
    <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CqtLKw7cJaY?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;start=5" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />       
    <form action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" id="form">
      <a name="contact-link"></a>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Information Pack by Email</legend>
        <label for="emailme">Email Address:</label><br />
        <input name="emailme" type="email" id="emailmeinput" placeholder="Your email address"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" formaction="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have edited to correct the syntax. As Andriy said, there was a missing '}' after '.nav-button:hover'. I also added 'left: 0;' and 'right: 0;' to '#nav-bar'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add right and left rules with zero value:

```
#nav-bar {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```css
#mainbody {
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: garamond, serif;
}

#h1title {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 16px 8px 16px;
  font-size: 38px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#header-img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

  #nav-bar {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: black;
}

.nav-button {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.30;
}

#video {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#form {
  
}

legend {
  font-weight: 700;
}

#submit {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Quality Prints</title>
  </head>
  <body id="mainbody">
    <a name="home-link"></a>
    <header id="header">
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <button class="nav-button"><a class="nav-link" href="#home-link">Home</a></button>
        <button class="nav-button"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a></button>
        <button class="nav-button"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact-link">Contact</a></button>
      </nav>
      <h1 id="h1title">Quality Prints ™</h1><hr />
      <img id="header-img" src="http://i66.tinypic.com/157ltle.jpg">
      
    </header>
    <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CqtLKw7cJaY?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;start=5" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />       
    <form action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" id="form">
      <a name="contact-link"></a>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Information Pack by Email</legend>
        <label for="emailme">Email Address:</label><br />
        <input name="emailme" type="email" id="emailmeinput" placeholder="Your email address"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" formaction="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much to joshmoto & Andriy. Andriy, your answer was perfect and helped me solve the problem. Can either of you also help me centre my video? It used to be centred before I made a change a while back, but I've completely forgotten what that change was. 

I've also added padding to the 'Submit' button to move down and away from the email box. Again, this used to work but is no longer doing so.

Comment: You had missing comma after your `.nav-button:hover` CSS rule. Adding comma fixed video position, please check my updated answer's example

Answer (score 0):

Your body width is set to `800px`; which is a little odd.

So your `.navbar` width is inherited by this width. Which makes it look not centered because the window is not `800px`;

Answer (score 0):

Just add `width: 100%;` to `#nav-bar` - a fixed element doesn't have full width by default, you have to define it. (and then the buttons will center within these 100%):

(note: `left: 0; right: 0` will bring the same result, since that way the left and right ends are defined, which also results in 100% width)

```css
  #mainbody {
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: garamond, serif;
}

#h1title {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 16px 8px 16px;
  font-size: 38px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#header-img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#nav-bar {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: black;
}

.nav-button {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.30;
  #video {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  #form {}
  legend {
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  #submit {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Quality Prints</title>
</head>

<body id="mainbody">
  <a name="home-link"></a>
  <header id="header">
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <button class="nav-button"><a class="nav-link" href="#home-link">Home</a></button>
      <button class="nav-button"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a></button>
      <button class="nav-button"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact-link">Contact</a></button>
    </nav>
    <h1 id="h1title">Quality Prints ™</h1>
    <hr />
    <img id="header-img" src="http://i66.tinypic.com/157ltle.jpg">

  </header>
  <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/CqtLKw7cJaY?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;start=5" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe><br />
  <form action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" id="form">
    <a name="contact-link"></a>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Information Pack by Email</legend>
      <label for="emailme">Email Address:</label><br />
      <input name="emailme" type="email" id="emailmeinput" placeholder="Your email address"><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" formaction="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```